# autofill event not triggered by chrome for ios? angualr2

Tags: angular, dom-events, onchange, angular2-forms, autofill

I developed an angular2 form using template driven syntax. The problem is, when we autofill the form in Chrome for iOS, and press submit button, it is throwing a validation alert. After through investigation, I understood that, the change event is not triggered in Chrome for iOS after autofilling the form. Is there any workaround for this? I deleted the Chrome app and reinstalled again, but still issue persists.